# How to add C++ QQuickPaintedItem in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmake, qt6

I want to add C++ class like this *notchedrectangle.hpp* to QML:

```
#ifndef NOTCHEDRECTANGLE_HPP
#define NOTCHEDRECTANGLE_HPP

#include <QtQml/qqmlregistration.h>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>

class NotchedRectangle : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    NotchedRectangle();

    void paint(QPainter* painter) override;

    QColor color() const;
    void setColor(QColor color);

signals:
    void colorChanged();

private:
    QColor m_color;
};

#endif // NOTCHEDRECTANGLE_HPP
```

I have qmake build system, but don't know - what should I add in qmake file.

My filesystem looks like that:

[image]

I tried to add to qmake file this strings:

```
CONFIG += qmltypes
QML_IMPORT_NAME = UI.NR
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
INCLUDEPATH += UI/NotchedRectangle
```

But they will cause error:

> [Makefile.Debug:1175: qlauncher_metatypes.json] Error 1

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: You should use [`qmlRegisterType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType).

Comment: @m7913d I used qmlRegisterType - it works fine. But it's old technology, that doesn't support by Qt Designer

Comment: I don't think it is "old" technology. It's the way to go (if you want to use C++ types in QML). [This thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/58216/qt-designer-not-showing-components-when-using-a-c-import-in-qml) may solve your problem related to using it in Qt Designer (but I'm not familiar with it, I edit the QML files in text mode).

Comment: @m7913d After `Qt5.15` It is in fact old. ([reference](https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-type-registration-in-qt-5.15))

Comment: This is not the OP's answer, but if you need a notched rectangle, I recommend using QML itself. Check the background item in [this](https://github.com/SMR76/qooey/blob/master/Qooey/Dial.qml) file.

Comment: @SMR Thanks, but there are lots of custom c++ objects. NotchedRectangle is the most simple and good as example. I used qmlRegisterType without Qt Designer. But now I want to add support for Qt Designer and use modern features :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QML_IMPORT_NAME is not a name of class!**

It's the name of package and must be different.

I use "Custom".

Next you must include class in main.cpp

And finally - you should make **Re**compile

Comment: According to the [qt documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qqmlengine.html#QML_ELEMENT) for `QML ELEMENT` (*using its class or namespace name as the QML element name*), the class name will be used if a name is not specified . Also, there is no need to include anything in main. And yes, it is necessary to run qmake and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

you should import in qml file after exposing the class:

```
import UI.NR 1.0
```

I suggest you to change UI.NR to smth else which has no dot in it.

Then take an instance:

WhatEverYouNamed {

}

Comment: The class name (`NotchedRectangle`) will be used if no names are specified.
Dotted names are also not an issue.

Comment: If I don't edit qmake file - I have error "unknown module" in QML. Else - I have error: [Makefile.Debug:1175: qlauncher_metatypes.json] Error 1